# Post commit deliver hook for RTC

Tags: jenkins, continuous-delivery, rational-team-concert

I have a working Jenkins setup that can pull source code from RTC (Jazz server) and build etc. I can run this Jenkins job on demand or schedule to run at a random interval. However, now I am exploring as to how I can run this job only on detecting a change in the repository (e.g. new change set is delivered). I dont want to use the polling mechanism that Jenkins provide and I want RTC's post commit process to call my Jenkins job remotely.

Please can anyone guide me how I do it? Thank you.,

Comment: I'm also looking for the same. By any chance you have found the solution?
Do let me know!